Receive notification in Google chat from Box thru webhooks
It's my first time doing this with an external app (was doing something like this with apps script), so would really appreciate your guidance.
I created a google chat webhook thru this guide, and copied the URL.
In Box Dev Console, I created a new app then a V2 webhook in it with the following details (below). However, when I tried doing any of the triggers, I was not able to receive any notifications.
I'm not sure what else I need to do. Hope you can guide me on this. Thanks!
Webhook settings:

